# Styled text in JavaFX?

Tags: java, text, colors, styles, javafx-2

I'm switching my chat client over from Swing to JavaFX, and I have run into a graphical problem. Previously, I was using a `JTextPane` to insert styled text, but upon switching to FX, I could not find a single component capable of doing what the `JTextPane` did, and from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9135668/1275092) answer, I know that FX's `TextPane` will not do the job either. Sorry if this is obvious to you JavaFX veterans, but I can't quite seem to find anything.

Please, if you could recommend a component like this, it would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Styled text will is available in JavaFX 8 (included in jdk8 and jre8) via the [TextFlow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html) component.

Here are the [details](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Rich+Text+API+Details) and [samples](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Rich+Text+API+Samples) of the feature.

The feature was implemented by the following [Multi-line, multi-style, rich text support issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8100566) and the related issues it references.

For older (now obsolete) JavaFX versions such as JavaFX 2.2, use a [WebView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) to display styled text and an [HTMLEditor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html) to edit it. Or you can place multiple Text or Label nodes in a [FlowPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html).

Comment: Thank you :) But, (correct me if I'm wrong) it seems as though the [final release date will be January 13, 2013](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk8-dev/2012-April/000942.html). If this is the case, should I plan my project using `WebView`, or should I wait for JDK 8 to be released?

Comment: JDK 8 is currently scheduled for general availability on: [9/9/13](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/).  For JDK 7, I'd advise using `WebView` to apply multiple styles to text.

Comment: I have the same problem. I append the postings at the end of the page. Is there a simple way to let the webview focus on the end of the page? Or do I have to use an anchor-Tag within the page and a related URL?

Comment: @wnck focusing on a location in a WebView is a different topic.  Please create a new question to for that.

Comment: Update. JDK 8 is scheduled to be available in [March 2014](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/)

Comment: Dang, details and samples links are broken now. :(

Comment: Yeah, the locations moved.  I updated the links to fix them.