# Spell check text in TextArea

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

How I can spell check text typed from the user into TextArea?

Is this possible with this JavaFX component?

Can I use standard spellchecker from Java for JavaFX?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlighting Strings in JavaFX TextArea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128535/highlighting-strings-in-javafx-textarea)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaFX Spell checker using RichTextFX how to create right click suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72204764/javafx-spell-checker-using-richtextfx-how-to-create-right-click-suggestions)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [CodeArea](https://github.com/TomasMikula/CodeAreaFX) to highlight the errors.

```
CodeArea codeArea = new CodeArea();
codeArea.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldText, newText) -> {
    List<IndexRange> errors = spellCheck(newText);
    for(IndexRange error: errors) {
        codeArea.setStyleClass(error.getStart(), error.getEnd(), "spell-error");
    }
});

List<IndexRange> spellCheck(String text) {
    // Implement your spell-checking here.
}
```

In addition, set the error style in your stylesheet

```css
.spell-error {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, red, 2, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Note that you need JDK8 to use CodeArea.