# Change substring color in JavaFX Text Area

Tags: text, colors, substring, javafx-8

I need to change substring text from `Text Area` in `JavaFX` for example in text below `static` and `void` be red.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

I don't know about `CSS` is there any simple code or tutorial?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlighting Strings in JavaFX TextArea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128535/highlighting-strings-in-javafx-textarea)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TextArea does not support anything like rich text different formatting within one component. I would propose you look into directions of

1. TextFlow - see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html.
   It is meant for static display of rich text, but it does not provide editing. The Oracle tutorial may be a viable starting point: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/text-settings.htm
2. WebView - see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html.
   WebView can be used to display HTML content. There are several ways to utilize this. You may construct your formatted and colored text as HTML code and set it as WebView content - or you even load one of the popular JavaScript source code formatters/highlighters into the WebView component.

If you are about to create something like a java source code view in JavaFX, you might want to have a look on the 2nd approach. A short sketch (using the ACE Editor libraries, done for JavaScript syntax coloring) might look like this:

First, initialize the WebView with your HTML, here done in an FXML controller:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    WebEngine engine = this.webView.getEngine();
    engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    engine.setOnAlert(new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>() {

      @Override
      public void handle(WebEvent<String> t) {
        String data = t.getData();
        System.out.println("alert: " + data);
        textArea.appendText(data);
      }
    });
    engine.load(this.getClass().getResource("content/basics-javascript.html").toExternalForm());
  }
```

Second part: `content/basics-javascript.html` contains an HTML page that loads the JavaScript libraries necessary for the formatting and highlighting:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        #editor { 
            position: absolute;
            top: 30px;
            right: 5px;
            bottom: 5px;
            left: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            background-color: #eee;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>ACE-Editor</div>
    <div id="editor">
    function foo(items) {
        var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
        return x;      

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/ace/ace.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var editor = ace.edit('editor');

      editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I want to write simple IDE‌ for a Compiler project and I need simple text editor that support substring coloring. my project is in java. I want to use JavaFX in swing and write my compiler with java. is it a good approach‌? ?

Comment: Yes, it is a good approach Karo.  Upvote, mark correct and go forth and prosper.