# JavaFX: How to change the color of text in TextArea corresponding to the selectRange

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-css

I am planning to get the range of selected text from TextArea and change the font color of the selectRange. My TextArea is initialized as a part of FXML file. I'm able to get the selectRange by using textArea.getSelection(), I would like to color the text in the range returned by above method. Please suggest me how to do it.

Comment: Not too clear, do you simply want to make the `TextArea` show a different color whenever texts are being selected, or you want to format the selected text such that it would have a different color?

Comment: I would want to format the selected text to have different color. Apologies for not being clear I'm fairly new to JavaFX.

Comment: I'm not sure if you really understood what I meant. Former means that you are trying to change look and feel of the `TextArea`. On the other hand, the latter means that the text itself would be a rich text, and this formatting stays when you copy this out to another text editor. Also for the latter, it would become possible to have various colors at different segment of the whole text.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to be more precise. I'm trying to build a text highlight application. All the highlighted strings from my TextArea should be colored, lets say with yellow font. Such that even after I remove the highlight, the previously highlighted text should have a color format to indicate its a highlighted text.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I would recommend to go with any rich text controls(RichTextFX) for your requirement. But if you are very specific with using TextArea, check the below approach.

The approach that I am providing may not be a correct solution or it may not suit to your exact requirement. But it can help you to think in that direction.

This is based on the idea provided(by @en_Knight) in [Highlighting Strings in JavaFX TextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128535/highlighting-strings-in-javafx-textarea/53332158#53332158). I recommend to first go thorugh this OP and then check my below implementation.

I had created a custom TextArea control, which works on the same principle provided in the mentioned OP. i.e, blending the nodes to get the desired effects. You can check different blend effects by changing the value of the combobox in the demo. I assume for your requirement you may need BlendMode.ADD

The highlight still remains while you are selecting the text.
[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.effect.BlendMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.PathElement;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomTextAreaDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        final VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setSpacing(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        final Scene sc = new Scene(root, 600, 300);
        stage.setScene(sc);
        stage.show();

        final CustomTextArea customTextArea = new CustomTextArea();
        customTextArea.setText(
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.");
        customTextArea.setWrapText(true);
        customTextArea.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 15px;");
        VBox.setVgrow(customTextArea, Priority.ALWAYS);

        final Button highlight = new Button("Highlight");
        final TextField stF = new TextField("40");
        final TextField enF = new TextField("51");
        final HBox hb = new HBox(highlight, stF, enF);
        hb.setSpacing(10);
        highlight.setOnAction(e -> {
            customTextArea.highlight(Integer.parseInt(stF.getText()), Integer.parseInt(enF.getText()));
        });

        final Button remove = new Button("Remove Highlight");
        remove.setOnAction(e -> customTextArea.removeHighlight());

        final Label lbl = new Label("Resize the window to see if the highlight is in align with text");
        lbl.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 17px;-fx-font-style:italic;");
        final HBox rb = new HBox(remove, lbl);
        rb.setSpacing(10);

        ComboBox<BlendMode> blendModes = new ComboBox<>();
        blendModes.getItems().addAll(BlendMode.values());
        blendModes.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, old, blend) -> {
            customTextArea.getHighlightPath().setBlendMode(blend);
        });
        blendModes.getSelectionModel().select(BlendMode.ADD);

        root.getChildren().addAll(hb, rb,blendModes, customTextArea);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    class CustomTextArea extends TextArea {
        /**
         * Start position of the highlight.
         */
        private int highlightStartPos = -1;

        /**
         * End position of the highlight.
         */
        private int highlightEndPos = -1;

        /**
         * Path node to act as highlight.
         */
        private final Path highlightPath = new Path();

        /**
         * Node to keep reference of the selectionGroup node of the TextArea.
         */
        private Group selectionGroup;

        /**
         * Node to keep reference of the all contents of the TextArea.
         */
        private StackPane contentPane;

        /**
         * Node to keep reference of the content node.
         */
        private Region textContent;

        /**
         * Specifies whether the selection of text is done for purpose of highlighting.
         */
        private boolean highlightInProgress = false;

        public CustomTextArea() {
            highlightPath.setStyle("-fx-fill:red");
            highlightPath.setMouseTransparent(true);
            highlightPath.setManaged(false);
            highlightPath.setStroke(null);
            textProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> removeHighlight());
            widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
                if (highlightStartPos > -1 && highlightEndPos > -1 && selectionGroup != null) {
                    highlightInProgress = true;
                    selectRange(highlightStartPos, highlightEndPos);
                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Highlights the range of characters in the text area.
         *
         * @param startPos Start position of the character in the text
         * @param endPos   End position of the character in the text
         */
        public void highlight(final int startPos, final int endPos) {
            highlightStartPos = startPos;
            highlightEndPos = endPos;
            highlightInProgress = true;
            selectRange(highlightStartPos, highlightEndPos);
        }

        public Path getHighlightPath() {
            return highlightPath;
        }

        @Override
        protected void layoutChildren() {
            super.layoutChildren();
            if (selectionGroup == null || contentPane == null) {
                final Region content1 = (Region) lookup(".content");
                if (content1 != null) {
                    // Looking for the Group node that is responsible for selection
                    content1
                            .getChildrenUnmodifiable()
                            .stream()
                            .filter(node -> node instanceof Group)
                            .map(node -> (Group) node)
                            .filter(grp -> {
                                final boolean notSelectionGroup =
                                        grp.getChildren().stream().anyMatch(node -> !(node instanceof Path));
                                return !notSelectionGroup;
                            })
                            .findFirst()
                            .ifPresent(n -> {
                                n.boundsInLocalProperty().addListener((obs, old, bil) -> {
                                    if (highlightInProgress) {
                                        updateHightlightBounds();
                                    }
                                });
                                selectionGroup = n;
                            });
                    contentPane = (StackPane) content1.getParent();
                    textContent = content1;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Updates the highlight with the provided bounds.
         */
        private void updateHightlightBounds() {
            if (!selectionGroup.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
                final Path p = (Path) selectionGroup.getChildren().get(0);
                final List<PathElement> elements = new ArrayList<>(p.getElements());

                highlightPath.getElements().clear();
                highlightPath.getElements().addAll(elements);
                final Node textNode = textContent.lookup(".text");
                highlightPath.setLayoutX(textNode.getLayoutX());
                highlightPath.setLayoutY(textNode.getLayoutY());

                if (contentPane != null && !contentPane.getChildren().contains(highlightPath)) {
                    contentPane.getChildren().add(highlightPath);
                }
                highlightInProgress = false;
                Platform.runLater(this::deselect);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Removes the highlight in the text area.
         */
        public void removeHighlight() {
            if (contentPane != null) {
                contentPane.getChildren().remove(highlightPath);
            }
            highlightStartPos = -1;
            highlightEndPos = -1;
        }
    }
}
```